# Increase space between keyboard and TextField

Tags: flutter, keyboard, textfield, space

I have several `TextField` and `TextFormField` in my app, but I customized them so they can display an error message below them.

Because it now shows an error, the space between the actual TextField seems smaller.
So is there a way to increase the size between the keyboard and a widget when the screen scrolls up?

I'm assuming this space is a value set somewhere, but cannot seem to find it.

So this is not a question about making the screen scroll this works, it's about increasing the space between the keyboard.

Thanks.

Comment: validator in textformfield already display error below field. If your requirement is different try dialog or snackbar.

Comment: I have strict UI designs that I need to follow. The default error is insufficient and other methods are not acceptable. That is why I created a custom widget.

Answer (score 8):

Since you make use of `TextField` widgets, you can use the `scrollPadding` property which indicates how much space you want to have between so called `viewInsets` (usually something like the UI keyboard) and the `TextField` widget. So you can set something like `EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 32.0)` (default is 20.0).

Keep in mind: This does only work, if the surrounding `Scrollable` (like `ListView`) has enough space to scroll past the `TextField` widget to fit the given `scrollPadding` - otherwise you will see, that the `TextField` is right above the keyboard, "ignoring" the padding. To resolve that, you could place a `SizedBox` as the last entry in your `Scrollable` widget which ensures that there is enough place to scroll once the keyboard is shown:

```dart
ListView(
  TextField(
    scrollPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 32.0),
  ),
  SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 32.0),
),
```